# Does WCF really respect the standards for WS-Addressing Soap Faults

Tags: wcf, web-services, wcf-binding, soapfault, ws-addressing

I am interested whether [Predefined Faults](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-soap/#soapfaults) specified in [Web Services Addressing 1.0 - SOAP Binding](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-soap) are handled by WCF.

For example, does it respond with a "wsa:ActionMismatch" SoapFault in case the action is mismatch (specified in standard at 6.4.1.6 wsa:ActionMismatch).
Or does it respond with a SoapFault with subcode="wsa:MessageAddressingHeaderRequired" for any missing ws-addressing header (specified in standard at 6.4.2 Message Addressing Header Required)?

Based on these standards, such SoapFault should look like this:

```
<Fault xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <Code>
    <Value>Sender</Value>
    <Subcode>
      <Value>wsa:MessageAddressingHeaderRequired</Value>
    </Subcode>
  </Code>
  <Reason>
    <Text xml:lang="en-US">A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present</Text>
  </Reason>
  <Details>
    <wsa:ProblemHeaderQName>wsa:MessageID</wsa:ProblemHeaderQName>
  </Details>
</Fault>
```

I am curios what configuration needs to be made in order to respond with such SoapFault messages.